# Natural way to represent hash tables/dictionaries/maps in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I want to use a dictionary/map data structure in R, similar to Python's `dict` or C++ STL's `std::map` or `std::hash_map`.

I can do all of the following. Is there a difference in their use and/or performance? And if so, which is the best way to have such a data structure in R?

```
> mm = c()
> mm["my key"] = 10
> mm[["my key"]]
[1] 10
> mm
my key 
    10

> mm = list()
> mm["my key"] = 10
> mm[["my key"]]
[1] 10
> mm
$`my key`
[1] 10

> mm = vector()
> mm["my key"] = 10
> mm[["my key"]]
[1] 10
> mm
my key 
    10
```

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before.  Try a StackOverflow search for `[r] hash` and look at the answers.

Comment: Related: [In R, can I use a list as a hash? If so, why is it so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470447/in-r-can-i-use-a-list-as-a-hash-if-so-why-is-it-so-slow)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fastest will be an environment, since they're hashed by default.

```
e <- new.env()
e$my_key <- 10
ls(e)
```

Comment: If this is something you want to explore further, this post by the author of R in a Nutshell might be of interest: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/lookup-performance-in-r.html

Comment: Thanks, eventually I decided to use the `hash` package that wraps an environment.