# tidyverse's way to look up a value in data frame given a key

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose I have a data frame like the following

```
a=data.frame(x=1:3,y=c("a","b","c"))
```

where `y` is the key column. Sometimes I just want to look up a the value of `x` corresponding to a key in `y`. To accomplish this, I can

```
row.names(a)=a$y
a["b",c("x")]
```

Just like looking up a value of a given key in a Python dictionary.

Now I want to achieve the same thing using tidyverse's tibble. But since tibble does not have `row.names`, I have no idea how to do it.

My question is, what is the "most clever" way (or idiomatic way, to borrow a term from Python) to look up a single value in a tibble given a single key?

Comment: Try `rownames_to_column(a, 'rn') %>% filter(rn == 'b') %>% select(x)`

Comment: You're asking for `tidyverse` solution, but for the record - this is pretty convenient with `data.table`: `setkey(setDT(a), y)` and  then just `a["b"]`

Comment: A dataframe isn't the best way of representing this type of data, keys can be duplicated. You could use a named list

Comment: @JackBrookes Names can be duplicated too, e.g, `names(list(a = 1, a = 2))`, so I don't think a named list is really an improvement over a data.frame.

Comment: You seem to want the behavior of a hash table for item look up. That's not a a basic class in R and it's not a very "tidy" way of working with data, but there are techniques you can use. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299367/natural-way-to-represent-hash-tables-dictionaries-maps-in-r. The "idiomatic" way to do this in R is to not do many single item looks up, just do a merge or something. Had to say for sure since you don't talk much about why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: or: `filter(a, y == 'b') %>% pull(x)`

Comment: @MrFlick I'm well aware of the solution using environment. I just wanted to know how to do the same thing in tidyverse efficiently. My workflow can be implemented in tidyverse elegantly, except the part where a dictionary-like look-up is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of

```
filter(a, y == "b")$x
```

or

```
a[a$y == "b", "x"]
```

would be fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use something like this

```
mapping <- function(key, dictionary) {
  values <- dictionary[key, ]
  return(values)
}

mapping('b', a)
```

And here is the bonus if the dictionary is a `tibble` without rownames, you can do

```
mapping <- function(keys, dictionary) {
  keys <- tibble::tibble(key=keys)
  dictionary <- tibble::tibble(key=dictionary[[1]], value=dictionary[[2]])
  values <- dplyr::left_join(keys, dictionary, by='key') %>% dplyr::select('value') %>% dplyr::pull()
  return(values)
}
```

Those `mapping` functions will also work when you `x` is a vector.