# Data frame to nested list

Tags: r, performance, list, dataframe, nested

I have a dataframe which I read from a .csv file and looks like this:

```
              job    name `phone number`
            <chr>   <chr>          <int>
 1      developer    john            654
 2      developer    mike            321
 3      developer  albert            987
 4        manager    dana            741
 5        manager     guy            852
 6        manager    anna            936
 7      developer     dan            951
 8      developer   shean            841
 9 administrative  rebeca            357
10 administrative  krissy            984
11 administrative   hilma            651
12 administrative    otis            325
13 administrative   piper            654
14        manager   mendy            984
15        manager corliss            321

DT = structure(list(job = c("developer", "developer", "developer", 
"manager", "manager", "manager", "developer", "developer", "administrative", 
"administrative", "administrative", "administrative", "administrative", 
"manager", "manager"), name = c("john", "mike", "albert", "dana", 
"guy", "anna", "dan", "shean", "rebeca", "krissy", "hilma", "otis", 
"piper", "mendy", "corliss"), phone = c(654L, 321L, 987L, 741L, 
852L, 936L, 951L, 841L, 357L, 984L, 651L, 325L, 654L, 984L, 321L
)), .Names = c("job", "name", "phone"), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to transform it into a list of lists, where, for example:

```
myList$developer
```

would give me a list containing all developers, and then

```
myList$developer$john
```

would give me a list of phone numbers associated with developers named John. Is there any simple way of doing it?

If you're curious as to why I'd want to do something like that: the actual data frame I'm working with is huge, so finding a specific entry by 4 parameters (in this example I can find a specific entry with 2 parameters: job, name) takes way too much time using filter. I think that the hash table structure of a nested list might take a lot of time to build, but would be searchable in O(1), which definitely works for me.
If I'm wrong and you have a better way of doing it I'd love to hear it too.

Comment: `lapply(split(df,df$job), function(x) split(x$phone_number,x$name))` would do it.

Comment: @AndrewGustar that's the same as my answer ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a double `split` with `lapply` and the `drop = TRUE`-parameter for that. Using `drop = TRUE` will drop levels that do not occur, thus preventing the creation of empty list elements.

Using:

```
l <- split(dat, dat$job, drop = TRUE)
nestedlist <- lapply(l, function(x) split(x, x[['name']], drop = TRUE))
```

Or in one go:

```
nestedlist <- lapply(split(dat, dat$job, drop = TRUE),
                     function(x) split(x, x[['name']], drop = TRUE))
```

gives:

> ```
> > nestedlist
> $administrative
> $administrative$hilma
>               job  name phonenumber
> 11 administrative hilma         651
>
> $administrative$krissy
>               job   name phonenumber
> 10 administrative krissy         984
>
> $administrative$otis
>               job name phonenumber
> 12 administrative otis         325
>
> $administrative$piper
>               job  name phonenumber
> 13 administrative piper         654
>
> $administrative$rebeca
>              job   name phonenumber
> 9 administrative rebeca         357
>
>
> $developer
> $developer$albert
>         job   name phonenumber
> 3 developer albert         987
>
> $developer$dan
>         job name phonenumber
> 7 developer  dan         951
>
> $developer$john
>         job name phonenumber
> 1 developer john         654
>
> $developer$mike
>         job name phonenumber
> 2 developer mike         321
>
> $developer$shean
>         job  name phonenumber
> 8 developer shean         841
>
>
> $manager
> $manager$anna
>       job name phonenumber
> 6 manager anna         936
>
> $manager$corliss
>        job    name phonenumber
> 15 manager corliss         321
>
> $manager$dana
>       job name phonenumber
> 4 manager dana         741
>
> $manager$guy
>       job name phonenumber
> 5 manager  guy         852
>
> $manager$mendy
>        job  name phonenumber
> 14 manager mendy         984
> ```

---

Used data:

```
dat <- structure(list(job = c("developer", "developer", "developer", "manager", "manager", "manager", "developer", "developer", "administrative", "administrative", "administrative", "administrative", "administrative", "manager", "manager"),
                      name = c("john", "mike", "albert", "dana", "guy", "anna", "dan", "shean", "rebeca", "krissy", "hilma", "otis", "piper", "mendy", "corliss"),
                      phonenumber = c(654L, 321L, 987L, 741L, 852L, 936L, 951L, 841L, 357L, 984L, 651L, 325L, 654L, 984L, 321L)),
                 .Names = c("job", "name", "phonenumber"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"))
```

Answer (score 6):

> the actual data frame I'm working with is huge, so finding a specific entry by 4 parameters (in this example I can find a specific entry with 2 parameters: job, name) takes way too much time using filter. I think that the hash table structure of a nested list might take a lot of time to build, but would be searchable in O(1), which definitely works for me. If I'm wrong and you have a better way of doing it I'd love to hear it too.

Apparently name lookup [behaves like O(n), not O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20325761/).

A possibly better way would be to use data.table, which uses binary search.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT, key = c("job", "name"))

get_phones = function(..., d = DT) d[list(...), phone]
```

Example usage

```
get_phones("developer", "john")
# [1] 654

get_phones("administrative")
# [1] 651 984 325 654 357
```

See `vignette("datatable-keys-fast-subset")` or the (possibly outdated) [copy online](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).

Comment: not marking as solution, because it is not a solution to the question in the title, but it was a better fit for my needs. Thanks a lot!