# Fast grep with a vectored pattern or match, to return list of all matches

Tags: r, vectorization

I guess this is trivial, I apologize, I couldn't find how to do it.

I am trying to abstain from a loop, so I am trying to vectorize the process:
I need to do something like `grep`, but where the `pattern` is a vector. Another option is a `match`, where the `value` is not only the first location.

For example data (which is not how the real data is, otherswise I would exploit it structure):

```
COUNTRIES=c("Austria","Belgium","Denmark","France","Germany",
"Ireland","Italy","Luxembourg","Netherlands",
"Portugal","Sweden","Spain","Finland","United Kingdom")

COUNTRIES_Target=rep(COUNTRIES,times=4066)
COUNTRIES_Origin=rep(COUNTRIES,each=4066)
```

Now, currently I got a loop that:

```
var_pointer=list()
for (i in 1:length(COUNTRIES_Origin))
{     
var_pointer[[i]]=which(COUNTRIES_Origin[i]==COUNTRIES_Target)
 }
```

The problem with `match` is that `match(x=COUNTRIES_Origin,table=COUNTRIES_Target)` returns a vector of the same length as `COUNTRIES_Origin` and the value is the *first* match, while I need all of them.

The issue with `grep` is that `grep(pattern=COUNTRIES_Origin,x=COUNTRIES_Target)` is the given warning:
`Warning message:
In grep(pattern = COUNTRIES_Origin, x = COUNTRIES_Target) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe `is.element(COUNTRIES_Origin, COUNTRIES_Target)` ?

Comment: What is the output you want? Your loop code simply re-assigns var_pointer each time. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MrFlick yes... my bad, now it's a list.

Comment: Trying to vectorize MxN matches is fundamentally not very performant, no matter how you do it it's still MN operations. Use ***hashes*** instead for O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can just `lapply` over the list rather than `loop`.

```
lapply(COUNTRIES_Origin, function(x) which(COUNTRIES_Target==x))
```

Here I use which because `grep` seems to be better for partial matches and you're looking for exact matches.

Comment: Alas, this does not produce the desired improvement in performance, as it only hides the loop in the lapply.

Comment: @Elad663 Did you have this much redundancy in your real data? What about a solution like this: `ids <- split(1:length(COUNTRIES_Target), COUNTRIES_Target); ml <- ids[COUNTRIES_Origin]`. This does the collapsing of the target list first. Makes lookups much quicker but produces the same result.

Comment: Just played with `split` and it looks very promising! Will send a proper response in the morning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to vectorize MxN matches is fundamentally not very performant, no matter how you do it it's still MN operations.

Use ***hashes*** instead for O(1) lookup.

For recommendations on using the `hash` package, see [Can I use a list as a hash in R? If so, why is it so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470447/can-i-use-a-list-as-a-hash-in-r-if-so-why-is-it-so-slow)