# R: Fast hash search in lists (environment)

Tags: r, windows, hash, data.table, rcpp

I want to have a very quick search and it seems, that using hashes (via environments) is the best way. Now, I got an example to run with environments, but it does not return what I need.

Here is an example:

```
a <- data.table::data.table(a=c(1, 3, 5), b=c(2, 4, 6), time=c(10, 20, 30))  
my_env <- list2env(a)  
x <- a[2, .(a, b)] # x=c(3,4)  
found <- get("x", envir = my_env)
```

I would expect `found = c(3, 4, 20)` but receive `found = c(3, 4)`
(I want the whole row to be returned instead of the unknown row subset)

**Backround**: I have a huge list containing source and destination of routes calculated with osrm, e.g.

```
lattitude1, longitude1, lattitude2, longitude2, travel-time  
46.12, 8.32, 47.87, 9.92, 1036  
...
```

The list contains in a first example about 100000 rows. Using binary search in a data.table speeded up my code by a factor 100, but one search still takes 1 ms. As I have to search for many routes during a simulation (About 2e5 searches) I would like to get even faster.
**@Gregor**: I am a beginner in R, but I don't think my question is a duplicate:

1. I knew the second link , which is an abstract overview for experts listing possibilities. Furthermore, it is 4 years old.
2. I didn't know the first link, but from those answers I can't see whether I should switch to environments and how an implementation could work at all. There is also no discussion about searching a part of a huge list.

**Summary (Thanks to DigEmAll for his running example below)**:

- Using Rcpp on integers, the search is less memory consuming without any loss of quality. Futhermore, it is about a factor of 3 faster.
- Do not use hashed environments when you want to look up doubles (which have to be converted to strings).
- Implementation in existing code should be easy.

Comment: Mmh... I don't get what you are trying to achieve but there are some misconceptions here. First, `list2env` convert a list to and evironment and a data.frame (or data.table) is a list of columns... so in the end `my_env` will contain 3 variables `a,b,time` corresponding to the columns. Then, `get("x", envir=my_env)` search inside `my_env` for a variable called "x" but since it doesn't exist, it goes up in the environments hierarchy and finds `x` in the global environment (it's the `x` you've just defined)

Comment: BTW, keyed access to data.table rows it very very fast, so since you're already using data.table I don't think you need to use an environment...

Comment: @digEmAll: Ok:-) I understand. Is there a way, to use hash search in environments? See my edits above. Otherwise I will be waiting a lot... If it is helpful, I could upload a test program.

Comment: I think using hash searches in environments is the point of the `hash` package, see these (possible duplicates?) [Can I use list as a has in R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3470486/903061) and [Options for caching / memoization / hashing in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7262485/903061).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using enviroment and data.table, the code is pretty self-explanatory :

```
library(data.table)

# create a big random example (160k rows)
set.seed(123)
fromTo <- expand.grid(1:400,1:400)
colnames(fromTo) <- c('a','b')
DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(fromTo,time=as.integer(runif(nrow(fromTo), min = 1, max=500))))

# setup the environment to use it as hashtable:
# we simply put the times inside an enviroment using 
# a|b (concatenation of a with b) as key
timesList <- as.list(DF$time)
names(timesList) <- paste(DF$a,DF$b,sep='|')
timesEnv <- list2env(timesList)  

# setup the data.table to use it as hashtable
DT <- setDT(DF,key=c('a','b'))

# create search functions
searchUsingEnv <- function(a,b){
  time <- get(paste(a,b,sep='|'),envir=timesEnv,inherits=FALSE)  
  return(time)
}
searchUsingDataTable <- function(from,to){
  time <- DT[.(from,to),time]
  return(time)
}
```

**Benchmark :**

```
# benchmark functions
# i.e. we try to search ~16K rows in ourtwo kind of hashtables
benchEnv <- function(){
  n <- nrow(fromTo)
  s <- as.integer(n * 0.9)
  for(i in s:n){
    searchUsingEnv(fromTo[i,'a'],fromTo[i,'b'])
  }
}
benchDT <- function(){
  n <- nrow(fromTo)
  s <- as.integer(n * 0.9)
  for(i in s:n){
    searchUsingDataTable(fromTo[i,'a'],fromTo[i,'b'])
  }
}

# let's measure the performances
> system.time(benchEnv(), gcFirst = TRUE)
user  system elapsed 
2.26    0.00    2.30 
> system.time(benchDT(), gcFirst = TRUE)
user  system elapsed 
42.34    0.00   42.56
```

**Conclusions:**
environment seems much faster then data.table for repeated single key access, so you can try to use it.

---

## EDIT :

Enviroments have fast access but they can only have string keys which occupy more memory than doubles. So, I've added an example using `Rcpp` and `std::map<>` with a multiple values map :
(*note: if you are on Windows you need to install [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) in order to make Rcpp work*)

```
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

nRows <- 1e7

############# create data.table "DT" containing coordinates and times
generate_routes_dt <- function(nmax) {
  set.seed(123)
  routes <- data.table(lat1 = numeric(nmax),
    lng1 = numeric(nmax),
    lat2 = numeric(nmax),
    lng2 = numeric(nmax),
    time = numeric(nmax))
  tmp <- sample(seq(46, 49, length.out = nmax), nmax)
  routes$lat1 <- tmp
  tmp <- sample(seq(8, 10, length.out = nmax), nmax)
  routes$lng1 <- tmp
  tmp <- sample(seq(46, 49, length.out = nmax), nmax)
  routes$lat2 <- tmp
  tmp <- sample(seq(8, 10, length.out = nmax), nmax)
  routes$lng2 <- tmp
  tmp <- sample(seq(0, 1e7, length.out = nmax), nmax)
  routes$time <- as.integer(tmp)
  data.table::setkey(routes, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
  return(routes)
}

DT <- generate_routes_dt(nRows)

############# create data.table search function
searchUsingDataTable <- function(lat_1,lng_1,lat_2,lng_2){
  time <- DT[.(lat_1,lng_1,lat_2,lng_2),time]
  return(time)
}
#############

############# create Rcpp search function
# the following code create 2 functions: createMap and getTime
# usage:
#   map <- createMap(lat1Vec,lng1Vec,lat2Vec,lng2Vec,timesVec)
#   t <- getTime(map,lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
sourceCpp(code=
'
#include <Rcpp.h>

  class MultiKey {
  public:
    double  lat1;
    double  lng1;
    double  lat2;
    double  lng2;

    MultiKey(double la1, double ln1, double la2, double ln2)
      : lat1(la1), lng1(ln1), lat2(la2), lng2(ln2) {}  

    bool operator<(const MultiKey &right) const 
    {
      if ( lat1 == right.lat1 ) {
            if ( lng1 == right.lng1 ) {
                if ( lat2 == right.lat2 ) {
                    return lng2 < right.lng2;
                }
                else {
                    return lat2 < right.lat2;
                }
            }
            else {
                return lng1 < right.lng1;
            }
        }
        else {
            return lat1 < right.lat1;
        }
    }    
  };


  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  SEXP createMap(Rcpp::NumericVector lat1, 
                 Rcpp::NumericVector lng1, 
                 Rcpp::NumericVector lat2, 
                 Rcpp::NumericVector lng2, 
                 Rcpp::NumericVector times){
    std::map<MultiKey, double>* map = new std::map<MultiKey, double>;
    int n1 = lat1.size();
    int n2 = lng1.size();
    int n3 = lat2.size();
    int n4 = lng2.size();
    int n5 = times.size();
    if(!(n1 == n2 && n2 == n3 && n3 == n4 && n4 == n5)){
      throw std::range_error("input vectors lengths are different");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
      MultiKey key(lat1[i],lng1[i],lat2[i],lng2[i]);
      map->insert(std::pair<MultiKey, double>(key, times[i]));
    }
    Rcpp::XPtr< std::map<MultiKey, double> > p(map, true);
    return( p );
  }

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::NumericVector getTime(SEXP mapPtr, 
                              double lat1, 
                              double lng1, 
                              double lat2, 
                              double lng2){
    Rcpp::XPtr< std::map<MultiKey, double> > ptr(mapPtr);
    MultiKey key(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2);
    std::map<MultiKey,double>::iterator it = ptr->find(key);
    if(it == ptr->end())
        return R_NilValue;

    return Rcpp::wrap(it->second);
  }

')

map <- createMap(DT$lat1,DT$lng1,DT$lat2,DT$lng2,DT$time)

searchUsingRcpp <- function(lat_1,lng_1,lat_2,lng_2){
  time <- getTime(map,lat_1,lng_1,lat_2,lng_2)
  return(time)
}
#############

############# benchmark
set.seed(1234)
rowsToSearchOneByOne <- DT[sample.int(nrow(DT),size=nrow(DT),replace=FALSE),]

bench <- function(searchFun2Use){
  for(i in nrow(rowsToSearchOneByOne)){
    key <- rowsToSearchOneByOne[i,]
    searchFun2Use(key$lat1,key$lng1,key$lat2,key$lng2)
  }
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  bench(searchUsingRcpp),
  bench(searchUsingDataTable),
  times=100)
#############
```

Benchmark result :

```
Unit: microseconds
                        expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
      bench(searchUsingRcpp)  360.959  381.7585  400.4466  391.999  403.9985  665.597   100
 bench(searchUsingDataTable) 1103.034 1138.0740 1214.3008 1163.514 1224.9530 2035.828   100
```

**Note:**

I really don't think that using double as keys is a good idea... floating point values should be used to search using a certain tolerance or inside a range, not to look up for perfect match inside a map.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example :-)) I modified it to test it in my situation and it seems, that hash search is at best as good as DT for 1e5 rows or more. See my comments above and the gist. I would really appreciate, if you could have a look at it, as I would have expected the opposite result.

Comment: @Christoph: yes data.table is slower in my example due to the function call overhead (because it creates an intermediate data.table, it makes  a join with the big one etc)... enviroment is faster for single accces... so: if you're searching, a lot of times, only one single row use environment, otherwise if you're searching, few times, a lot of rows use data.table...

Comment: @Christoph: anyway, you should consider using Rcpp and write some functions using that (and maybe the standard library c++ map)...

Comment: I tried it in the gist, but environment was slower when searching for a single row! If I understand correctly, you state the opposite? btw, I could reproduce your results.

Comment: Mmh... your gist (a bit convoluted to be honest) seems to confirm that enviroments are still faster on my machine, even if not as much as in my example... anyway if you're doing a lookup for double values I wouldn't go for the environment approach since it relies on double to string conversion...

Comment: Added an RCpp example... still, I really don't think that using double as keys is a good idea... floating point values should be used to search using a certain tolerance, not to look up for perfect match inside a map...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Last question for my conclusion (to be written): Rcpp looks really good. Do I understand correcly, that you would use a different strategy? Which was it? I searched in the web but could not find anything.

Comment: @Christoph: I didn't get your question about strategy... do you mean my advice about not using doubles in lookup-dictionaries ?

Comment: Yes: "...I really don't think that using double as keys is a good idea...". So what about your Rcpp approach (To me this is still using double as keys)? - You mean, you would not use that? But what else then?

Comment: My Rcpp approach still uses doubles as keys (to reproduce your example), but I wanted to warn you since I really don't think it's a good idea because doubles are not really born for exact equality (e.g. check the result of this: `0.1+0.1+0.1==0.3` ). You should consider to convert your doubles for example to fixed integers by multiplying and truncating the doubles to a certain decimal place e.g. `46.12435934565 -> 46124359`. Then use Rcpp similary but with integers instead of doubles...